# Unable to insert into the database by using cURL

Tags: php, curl

I am not receiving any errors when trying to insert data in the database. But it at the same time there is nothing being entered.

I watched a video that has the same example. I tried a different statement for creating the Mysqli object and still do not work.

```
//This part of the code is in another php file
<?php
    $data = array("name"=>"patrick", "age"=>"25");
    $string = http_build_query($data);
    $ch = curl_init("http://localhost//data.php");
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$string);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
?>

//This part of the code is in the data.php
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['age']))
    {
      //$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","testPost");
        $db = new Mysqli("localhost","root","password","testPost");
        $name = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
        $age = (int)$_POST['age'];
        $query = "INSERT INTO data SET myData = '$name, $age'";
        $db->query($query);
    }
?>
```

I expect data to be inserted in a database. The database is called testPost and it has two columns called id and myData

Comment: Check if you have Curl on

Comment: how have you debugged it? is it the curl or the MySQL? it should be easy to test which is at issue here

Comment: @falconimogollon I get the following when I check the version of curl.                           curl 7.54.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin18.0) libcurl/7.54.0 LibreSSL/2.6.5 zlib/1.2.11 nghttp2/1.24.1
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz HTTP2 UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy

Comment: @Tim I check if everything was properly spelled, like database name, I check to see if I made any typos. For the record I am using a Mac for this curl testing and I don't think it should matter. I am not getting any error which makes debugging hard.

Comment: Are you sure your SQL statement is correct? Try adding ```echo $db->error;```

Comment: @David it doesn't output anything. Could it be that the data.php is never being reached? I noticed that even with a simple echo "string"; do to output anything. I am calling the other php file which should call the data.php

Comment: Any other suggestions? I am pretty new to php so for me to be stuck on such simple example, there is not much for me to try.

Comment: @PatrickAdjei Possibly. That info would come out if you ```echo curl_getinfo($ch)```.
Start by adding a debug line for every test. I.e. ```print_r($_POST);``` to ensure you have data, then test the database connection, then test the curl connection.

You could also try amending the insert statement like this: ```INSERT INTO data(name,age) VALUES($name, $age)```

Comment: @David yes you're correct. The insert statement was the problem. I should of mentioned it a few days back that this was the problem. Thank you for getting back to me.